# arguments imply differing numbers of rows

Tags: r

I am trying to analyse some ecological data with the r package rNEXT.
I have a list of 3 matrices, which is classed as "incidence_raw" in the package.  My data matches the package example data in format exactly.  The matrices contain 0 and 1.

```
> str(blob)
List of 3
 $ : int [1:119, 1:109] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : int [1:119, 1:122] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : int [1:119, 1:106] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> out = iNEXT (blob, q=c(0,1,2), datatype ="incidence_raw")
Error in data.frame(site = rownames(out), out) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3
```

I have absolutely no idea what the error could be because my data is pretty much identical to the example data.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is rNEXT? I can't find that package on CRAN.

Comment: Always make your code reproducible, and in this case that would mean getting the library name right, and the corresponding include/require statement, and a link to the library doc would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find package "rNEXT", so I guess you actually mean R package `iNEXT`.

It seems your input format is incorrect. Take a look at the third example in `?iNEXT`:

```
require(iNEXT);
data(ant);
t <- round(seq(10, 500, length.out=20));
out3 <- iNEXT(ant$h500m, q=1, datatype="incidence_freq", size=t, se=FALSE);
```

You can see that the format of `ant` is different from the format of your `blob`:

```
str(ant);
#List of 5
# $ h50m  : num [1:228] 599 330 263 236 222 195 186 183 182 129 ...
# $ h500m : num [1:242] 230 133 131 123 78 73 65 60 60 56 ...
# $ h1070m: num [1:123] 150 99 96 80 74 68 60 54 46 45 ...
# $ h1500m: num [1:57] 200 144 113 79 76 74 73 53 50 43 ...
# $ h2000m: num [1:15] 200 80 59 34 23 19 15 13 8 8 ...
```

`ant` is a list of numeric vectors, not a list of matrices (as in your case).

I'm not familiar with ecological data/modelling, but perhaps you need to do:

```
blob <- lapply(blob, colSums);
out <- iNEXT(blob, q = c(0, 1, 2), datatype = "incidence_raw");
```

Comment: sorry yes it  is iNEXT. The ant dataset is for "incidence_freq" style data.  Mine is "incidence_raw" which is exemplified by the 'ciliates' dataset in the iNEXT guides, which is a list of matrices like mine.  However, unfortunately they do not provide a full analysis of the this last data type.  Just mention it breifly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I think it might help to leave the solution from [post](https://github.com/JohnsonHsieh/iNEXT/issues/29#issuecomment-384155056) on github here as well:

(1) You should load the function described here (ggiNEXT.iNEXT) into your R environment: #25

(2) Your list of data frames or matrices must be named (just like the ciliates example). You can try skipping the names(data.list) part below and you'll get the same error message as you stated above.

An example below with the BCI dataset from the vegan package --

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(vegan)
library(iNEXT)

data(BCI)
t.BCI <- as.data.frame(t(BCI))

BCI.1 <- t.BCI[1:225, 1:15]
BCI.1 <- as.matrix((BCI.1 > 0) + 0)

BCI.2 <- t.BCI[1:225, 16:27]
BCI.2 <- as.matrix((BCI.2 > 0) + 0)

BCI.3 <- t.BCI[1:225, 28:30]
BCI.3 <- as.matrix((BCI.3 > 0) + 0)

data.list <- list(BCI.1, BCI.2, BCI.3)

names(data.list) <- c("BCI.1", "BCI.2", "BCI.3")

out.raw <- iNEXT(data.list, datatype="incidence_raw", endpoint=100)
ggiNEXT.iNEXT(out.raw)
```